# difference between client.end() and client.quit() in redis?

Tags: redis

Right now I am using redis in node js app. While go through the redis node js code, two functions end() and quit() are used. I am confused with that thing

Answer (score 7):

**client.end()**  Forcibly close the connection to the Redis server. Note that this does not wait until all replies have been parsed.

**client.quit()**  This sends the quit command to the redis server and ends cleanly right after all running commands were properly handled. If this is called while reconnecting (and therefor no connection to the redis server exists) it is going to end the connection right away instead of resulting in further reconnections! All offline commands are going to be flushed with an error in that case.

Comment: Is client.quit the preferred way to close a connection to Redis? @Shubham Batra

Comment: It matters according to requirement. but by default client.quit is preferable.